# Ragged Tensors of non-text data as input for LSTM

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am learning about ragged tensors with applications for particle tracking. I have the following minimal example which reproduces a the error i keep experiencing.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Input, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 

n=10
data_n = 32
batch_size=8
window_length=8
splits = [n]*data_n

#### Create a ragged tensor with shape (32, None, 8)
t0 = tf.zeros([data_n * n, window_length])        
t1 = tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_lengths(t0, splits) 
max_seq = t1.bounding_shape()[-1]

#### Define Model
def create_model(batch_size, window_length, max_seq):
    lstm_model = Sequential([
        Input(
            batch_shape=[batch_size, None, window_length],
                batch_size=batch_size,
                dtype=tf.float32,
                ragged=True
        ),
        LSTM(
            max_seq,
            return_sequences=True,
            input_shape=(window_length, None)
        ),
        TimeDistributed(Dense(units=1))
    ])
    return lstm_model

lstm_model = create_model(batch_size=batch_size, window_length=window_length, max_seq=max_seq)
lstm_model(t1[0:8])
```

When i execute the above code i get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_FallbackException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_cudnn_rnn_ops.py in cudnn_rnnv3(input, input_h, input_c, params, sequence_lengths, rnn_mode, input_mode, direction, dropout, seed, seed2, num_proj, is_training, time_major, name)
   1889     try:
-> 1890       _result = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_FastPathExecute(
   1891         _ctx._context_handle, tld.device_name, "CudnnRNNV3", name,

_FallbackException: Expecting float value for attr dropout, got int

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-7609e2877e20> in <module>
      1 lstm_model = create_model(batch_size=batch_size, window_length=window_length, max_seq=max_seq)
----> 2 lstm_model(t1[0:8])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    966           with base_layer_utils.autocast_context_manager(
    967               self._compute_dtype):
--> 968             outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    969           self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
    970           self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, input_masks)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    275       if not self.built:
    276         self._init_graph_network(self.inputs, self.outputs, name=self.name)
--> 277       return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    278 
    279     outputs = inputs  # handle the corner case where self.layers is empty

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    715                                 ' implement a `call` method.')
    716 
--> 717     return self._run_internal_graph(
    718         inputs, training=training, mask=mask,
    719         convert_kwargs_to_constants=base_layer_utils.call_context().saving)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in _run_internal_graph(self, inputs, training, mask, convert_kwargs_to_constants)
    886 
    887           # Compute outputs.
--> 888           output_tensors = layer(computed_tensors, **kwargs)
    889 
    890           # Update tensor_dict.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py in __call__(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs)
    652 
    653     if initial_state is None and constants is None:
--> 654       return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
    655 
    656     # If any of `initial_state` or `constants` are specified and are Keras

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    966           with base_layer_utils.autocast_context_manager(
    967               self._compute_dtype):
--> 968             outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    969           self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
    970           self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, input_masks)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py in call(self, inputs, mask, training, initial_state)
   1178         # GPU implementation when GPU is available.
   1179         if can_use_gpu:
-> 1180           last_output, outputs, new_h, new_c, runtime = gpu_lstm(
   1181               **gpu_lstm_kwargs)
   1182         else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py in gpu_lstm(inputs, init_h, init_c, kernel, recurrent_kernel, bias, mask, time_major, go_backwards, sequence_lengths)
   1404       inputs = array_ops.reverse_sequence_v2(
   1405           inputs, sequence_lengths, seq_axis=seq_axis, batch_axis=batch_axis)
-> 1406     outputs, h, c, _, _ = gen_cudnn_rnn_ops.cudnn_rnnv3(
   1407         inputs,
   1408         input_h=init_h,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_cudnn_rnn_ops.py in cudnn_rnnv3(input, input_h, input_c, params, sequence_lengths, rnn_mode, input_mode, direction, dropout, seed, seed2, num_proj, is_training, time_major, name)
   1899     except _core._FallbackException:
   1900       try:
-> 1901         return cudnn_rnnv3_eager_fallback(
   1902             input, input_h, input_c, params, sequence_lengths,
   1903             rnn_mode=rnn_mode, input_mode=input_mode, direction=direction,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_cudnn_rnn_ops.py in cudnn_rnnv3_eager_fallback(input, input_h, input_c, params, sequence_lengths, rnn_mode, input_mode, direction, dropout, seed, seed2, num_proj, is_training, time_major, name, ctx)
   1999   "direction", direction, "dropout", dropout, "seed", seed, "seed2", seed2,
   2000   "num_proj", num_proj, "is_training", is_training, "time_major", time_major)
-> 2001   _result = _execute.execute(b"CudnnRNNV3", 5, inputs=_inputs_flat,
   2002                              attrs=_attrs, ctx=ctx, name=name)
   2003   if _execute.must_record_gradient():

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Invalid input_h shape: [1,8,8] [10,8,8] [Op:CudnnRNNV3]
```

The `10` refers to the number of units in the `LSTM`-layer, which is equal to the bounding shape of `t1`. The two `8`'s refer to `batch_size` and `window_length`. I thought that `1` refered to the output shape, but that is not the case, since it does not change when i add more units to the `Dense`-layer the number remains the same.

Comment: I was able to run your code successfully without getting any error in google colab, can you check again.

Answer (score 2):

When working with `tf.RaggedTensor` with sequences of variable sizes, you want to set the `batch_size = 1` and you want to ensure that sequence_length passed to the LSTM is `None`.

This is because even though `tf.RaggedTensor` are a great storage for variable sized sequences in form of numpy arrays, the LSTM still expects the same length sequence for each batch. You can however have variable sized sequences across batches.

Making those changes should fix the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug I encountered as well. It is specific to combination of the below:

Keras implementation of RNN / LSTM Tensorflow version Using GPU And using RaggedTensor

The erroneous source code is comparing shape of ragged tensor of input hidden state of RNN cell with shape of hidden state

The ragged dimension is shown as 1 in the error message.
I was able to replicate same error using your code and Tensorflow 2.2.0

Changing code to remove ragged tensor or running on cpu or different tensorflow version I was able to get this code to work

Comment: Sounds interesting.. `The erroneous source code` could you point to an issue on the github repo which confirms this is an open bug report?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cb89425db9e96681c796bcdaa32440d4ac561e23/tensorflow/core/kernels/cudnn_rnn_ops.cc#L612

Comment: I haven't found one yet, may be you can start one